# Interact with EBean Model classes in PlayFramework through h2-browser and console

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2, ebean

Is it possible to interactively execute commands in the Play Console to change the Model of a Play application and see the changes in the in-memory database?

I know that it is possible to browse the in-memory database through the h2-browser command in a Play application.

The steps that I follow are:

- Start `play` console
- Execute `h2-browser`
- Execute `run`
- Go to `http://localhost:9000` to refresh application and start Database
- Go to `http://192.168.56.1:8082/` to connect to the Database

I also know that it is possible to start the console and execute Scala commands. For example, if I have a model entity Person and I execute:

```
> play console
...
scala> import Models.Person
scala> val john = new Person("john")
scala> john.save()
```

It raises an exception:

```
    avax.persistence.PersistenceException: The default EbeanServer has not been defined? This is normally set via the ebean.datasource.default property. Otherwise it should
 be registered programatically via registerServer()
       at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean$ServerManager.getPrimaryServer(Ebean.java:178)
       at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean$ServerManager.access$300(Ebean.java:128)
       at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.save(Ebean.java:453)
       at play.db.ebean.Model.save(Model.java:91)
...
```

I think the reason is that it is using a different Play application...is it possible to refer to the application that is running on the other window? Or to execute run on Play in the background and be able to open the console later?

Answer (score 0):

*I hope you don't need this anymore, but since your question was one of the first result I got when I searched for the same topic, here is the solution, in case other people needs it.*

The problem is that when you launch the console you are not using the same instance of the running application, to use Ebean in the scala console just run first your app with this commands:

```
scala> import play.core._
scala> new StaticApplication(new java.io.File("."))
```

That's it! Now you can import your Ebean Model, instantiate it and play around with it.

For more information and tips on the Play console I found this post on [https://playlatam.wordpress.com](https://playlatam.wordpress.com/2012/04/01/play-framework-2-quicktip-interactively-play-with-your-application-from-the-scala-console/)